# SQL query laravel syntax

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

How can I query this:

```
SELECT *, due1 as newDate FROM equipments WHERE due1 <> "1990-01-01" 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, due2 as newDate FROM equipments where due2 <> "1990-01-01"
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, due3 as newDate FROM equipments WHERE due3 <> "1990-01-01" 
ORDER BY newDate ASC
```

in Laravel?

Comment: You can try using below two way from here [Laravel Eloquent Union query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196997/6429700) [Row query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37942103/6429700)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the solution was unionAll() the statements:

```
$TMUDue = Equipments::Where('due1', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                                ->select('*', 'due1 AS newDate');
$CalDue = Equipments::Where('due2', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                                ->select('*', 'due2 AS newDate');
$SerDue = Equipments::Where('due3', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                                ->select('*', 'due3 AS newDate');
$equipmentsDue = $SerDue->unionAll($CalDue)->unionAll($TMUDue)->orderBy('newDate' , 'ASC')->get();
```

Interesting that `union()` only results are single despite the `due1` and `due2` are `<> 1990-01-01` and the `unionAll()` results two entries for the same equipment on this example.

Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: the reason is UNION is basically a set operation and set has well defined distinct items so union doesn't contain any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you take look at the Laravel documentation under [unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#unions) you can create the multiple select statements and the last statement use the `union()` function and/or `unionAll()` function

Comment: Very well Trevor, thanks for this... using the unionAll()